# browscap.ini is not configured in php.ini

Tags: javascript

In my status report I'm still getting this error:

```
Browscap data   /   browscap.ini is not configured in php.ini.
```

When I searched on the internet I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663304/how-should-i-be-setting-browscap-ini-file) topic that suggested this:

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap = "C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
```

I've download full_php_browscap.ini file on [browscap.org](http://browscap.org/) and placed it in the root where my php.ini is also located (also changed the name to browscap.ini).

Then I've placed this in my php.ini file:

```
[browscap]
browscap = "/domains/mydomain.be/public_html/staging/browscap.ini"
```

But I'm still getting the error ... . My php.ini file is located in the same directory as the browscap.ini file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with the module [Browscap](https://www.drupal.org/project/browscap).